# Takes two login attempts for an RDP 6.1 session on an XP SP3 machine

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2

I've got a couple of users that when they connect to their VM's via RDP, the first log-in attempt tries to connect then doesn't. It just gives them their credientals screen again. Then they log in again and it works fine. Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Yes, I have this issue all the time when I type my password in incorrectly the first time.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the new version of RDP doesn't trust the old version's authentication token.  Users cannot cancel past the login, but you can at least save them a little time and tell them they don't need to put in a password. They still need to click OK as if they were logging in (clicking Cancel would abort the connection), but it doesn't matter what password they put in.